# The image is superimposed on another when using "Scale"

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, z-index

Good time of day. Faced with such a problem. The code consists of several images that zoom in when hovering. But increasing, part of the picture remains under the other. Tell me how to fix it

I made cards using grid
The inserted image shows what happens when you hover over the card. I want it to come to the fore when hovering  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CbE3.png)

```
<div class="feed">
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="feed__line1">
                <div class="card1">
                    <img class="image__card1" src="assets/images/Card.png" alt="#">
                    <h2 class="card1__content">Title1</h2>
                    <p class="card1__content">Subtitle</p>
                </div>

                <div class="card1">
                    <img class="image__card1" src="assets/images/Card.png" alt="">
                    <h2 class="card1__content">Title2</h2>
                    <p class="card1__content">Subtitle</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.feed__line1 {
    margin-top: 1%;
    max-height: 300px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    gap: 1%;
}

.card1 {
    position: relative;
}

.card1__content {
    left: 30px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.image__card1:hover {
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: Please could you clarify the problem. Which image is superimposed - is it because the one that is being scaled overlays stuff that is near to it? What would you like to happen instead?

Comment: @A Haworth take a look, please

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `position: absolute;` to `.image__card1` to solve that problem. You won't need the `z-index` on the `hover` state then.

```css
.feed__line1 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  gap: 1%;
}

.card1 {
  position: relative;
}

.card1__content {
  left: 30px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.image__card1 {
  position: absolute;
}
.image__card1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="feed">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="feed__line1">
      <div class="card1">
        <img class="image__card1" src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=1" alt="#">
        <h2 class="card1__content">Title1</h2>
        <p class="card1__content">Subtitle</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card1">
        <img class="image__card1" src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=2" alt="">
        <h2 class="card1__content">Title2</h2>
        <p class="card1__content">Subtitle</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```